# automatic differentiation on matrix-vector product

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, tensor-products, tensors

I was trying to derive a general formula for backward automatic differentiation of a matrix-vector product.

The task is basically the following:

$$A\cdot x= b$$

We assume that $\dfrac{dE}{db}$ is given (E is any value which is not in the scope of this question), I want to calculate $\dfrac{dE}{dA}$ and $\dfrac{dx}{dA}$.

I am stuck at writing a general form for $\dfrac{dE}{dA}$.

This is what I did:

$$\dfrac{dE}{dA} = \dfrac{dE}{db} \cdot \dfrac{db}{dA}$$

Writing this down in tensor notation:

$$\dfrac{dE}{db_i}(e_i) \cdot \dfrac{db_j}{dA_{mn}}(e_j \otimes e_m \otimes e_n)$$

But I did not manage to simplify this. Obviously a tensor of rank 2 should be the result.

I guessed the following result:

$$\color{red}{\dfrac{dE}{db_i} \dfrac{db_j}{dA_{mn}} (e_i) \cdot (e_j \otimes e_m \otimes e_n)}$$
$$\color{red}{= \dfrac{dE}{db_i} \dfrac{db_j}{dA_{mn}} \delta_{in} (e_j \otimes e_m)}$$
$$\color{red}{= \dfrac{dE}{db_i} \dfrac{db_j}{dA_{mi}} (e_j \otimes e_m)}$$

I looked through my books to find a suitable solution but only found tensor product where the first tensor has a higher rank than the second one. The problem with my solution is especially that $b$ can be a different size than the second size dimension of $A$.

I am very happy if someone could help me here!

Greetings,
Finn

Comment: shouldn't it be ${dE\over db_i}{db_i \over d A_{mn}}$ ?

Comment: but I would end up with a tensor of rank 3 there and according to my basic understanding, this would not work.

Comment: When you differentiate ${dF(x(a),y(a))\over da}$  where $a$ is a scalar, you get ${dF\over dx} {dx\over da}+{dF\over dy} {dy\over da}$

Comment: But E is a scalar and A is not.

Comment: my issue wasn't with $A$ it was with $b$ ( equivalent to $x,y$ in my toy example)

Comment: mhm but this should be a tensor of rank 1, right?

Comment: $dE\over db_i$ is rank 1 , but the rest of the expression contracts it

Comment: How would you solve this problem then?

Comment: realize that $i=j$

Comment: Oh yeah damn. Thank you!

Comment: So more like:


$$\dfrac{dE}{dA_{mn}} = \sum_i {\dfrac{dE}{db_i} \cdot \dfrac{db_i}{dA_{mn}}}$$

with $\dfrac{db_i}{dA_{mn}} = x_n$

Comment: You got it. If the tensor is confusing you, try going back to simple cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and help! :)

Comment: wait! $\dfrac{db_i}{dA_{mn}} = x_n$ doesnt make sense.

Comment: Oh yeah. yeah yeah yeah i know

Comment: sorry :D that was confusing me aswell. I got it :)

Comment: I suggest you write it up as an answer and answer yourself

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I guess it is correct this way now :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @user619894 who suggested to use $i=j$, I got to the following:

$$\dfrac{dE}{dA_{mn}} = \sum_i {\dfrac{dE}{db_i} \cdot \dfrac{db_i}{dA_{mn}}}$$

It's important to see that $\dfrac{db_i}{dA_{mn}}$ is only different from $0$ if $m=i$.

Therefor the sum reduces to:

$$\dfrac{dE}{dA_{mn}} = \dfrac{dE}{db_m}\cdot x_n$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Let's use a colon for the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
}$$
We are given the following problem variables
$$\eqalign{
b &= Ax &\qiq &db = A\:dx + dA\:x \\
g &= \grad{\E}{b} &&\big({\rm gradient}\big) \\
}$$
Expand the differential of $\E$ and isolate its gradients
$$\eqalign{
d\E &= g:db \\
 &= g:\LR{A\:dx + dA\:x} \\
 &= \c{A^Tg}:{dx} + \c{gx^T}\!:{dA} \\
\grad{\E}{x} &= \c{A^Tg},\qquad\; \c{gx^T} = \grad{\E}{A} \\
\\
}$$

---

From the definition of the Frobenius product a number of handy formulas follow
$$\eqalign{
A:A &= \|A\|_F^2 \\
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A = \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
Applied to vectors (i.e. $\:n\times\o$ matrices)
it becomes the standard dot product
$$\eqalign{
a:b \;=\; a\cdot b \;=\; a^Tb \\
}$$